# Stellar systems: what is the difference between virial, dynamical and thermodynamic equilibrium?

Tags: galaxy, galactic-dynamics, star-systems, stellar-dynamics

I'm currently going through Binney & Tremaine (2008) on my own to learn about stellar dynamics. I also have been perusing additional online resources such as [this scholarpedia wiki](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/N-body_simulations_(gravitational)).

Often when distinguishing between collision-less vs collisional stellar systems, the virial theorem is invoked along with the equations for "crossing time" (also known as "dynamical time") and "relaxation time." A large galaxy is said to be collision-less because its relaxation time is many orders of magnitude higher than its age, whereas a dense stellar system (e.g., a globular cluster) is collisional because its relaxation time is less than its age.

But what is the relationship between this so-called "relaxed" state and virial, dynamical, and thermodynamic equilibrium? What do the three different kinds of equilibria intuitively mean?

For example, I have heard that large galaxies are assumed to be in virial equilibrium and then people derive "dynamical masses" (why not "virial masses"?). What would it take and/or mean for a large elliptical galaxy to be not just in virial equilibrium, but also in dynamical or thermodynamic equilibrium?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Thermal equilibrium**

Thermal equilibrium relies strongly on the idea of [equipartition of (kinetic) energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equipartition_theorem). In a stellar system, this means that the total kinetic energy is divided evenly amongst all the stars. This doesn't imply that the velocities are all the same; they can't, because not all the masses are the same.

**Dynamical equilibrium**

Dynamical equilibrium means that over dynamical timescales, the system is stable - basically, it will not succumb to core collapse due to a gravothermal instability. Note that it may not be possible for a system to reach thermal equilibrium, even if it is in dynamical equilibrium. In a system with two main types of stars, it must satisfy the Spitzer stability condition (see [Fregeau et al. (2001)](http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0111057v1.pdf) and [these results](http://modest15s.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/Spera.pdf)):
$$\left(\frac{M_2}{M_1}\right)\left(\frac{m_2}{m_1}\right)^{3/2}<0.16$$
where $M_1$ and $M_2$ are the total masses of types 1 and 2.

**Virial equilibrium**

Virial equilibrium comes about when the system satisfies the [virial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virial_theorem) (see [Meylan (2000)](https://cds.cern.ch/record/432240/files/0003390.pdf)), i.e.
$$2\langle T\rangle+\langle V\rangle=0$$
where $T$ and $V$ are kinetic and potential energies.

Comment: And note that virial equilibrium does not require thermal equilibrium because the kinetic energy can be distributed among the stars in any way.

Comment: Thanks both, just to make sure I understand: so the combination of thermal and dynamical equilibrium is "thermodynamical equilibrium" and it involves equipartition of energy among the constituents of the system, as well as long-term dynamical stability. Virial equilibrium seems much easier to work with rather than thermal or dynamical equilibrium because it involves long-term time average and it's not always clear that an observed, e.g., globular cluster is in thermal equilibrium. @RobJeffries & HDE: is gravothermal instability and its implications still studied intensively by astrophysicists?

Comment: @quantumflash Yes it is. Another instance to consider - the virial theorem fails where objects have internal degrees of freedom. In clusters this means binaries are problematic. It also now appears likely that clusters never reach equipartition.

Comment: Dear @RobJeffries, can you please offer a nice review or even recent research paper that explores the idea that stellar clusters never reach equipartition? Does this mean using the virial theorem to derive the mass of a globular cluster is not *perfectly* correct?

Comment: @quantumflash I said they never reach equipartition. They are likely to be in virial equilibrium (approximately). Virial equilibrium does not demand that the KE is distributed among the stars equally.

Comment: @quantumflash. N-body simulations: Spera et al. (2016) https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.03943 Trenti & van der Marel (2013) https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.2152 .  I am working on a paper that confirms the results of the former paper using radial velocity measurements in a rich open cluster.

Comment: Very cool @RobJeffries! Can I just ask how one learns enough N-body simulation tools to be able to carry out such theoretical experiments? Is simply reading Binney & Tremaine good enough, and then I should be able to just program simple gravity-based N-body simulations? And would N-body simulations as in those papers run on my own laptop (e.g., using Python), or would they need super-computers?

Comment: @quantumflash Some codes are public. I can't comment on your speed question; it depends on $N$.  But I would think you might be limited to a few hundred stars. http://www.ast.cam.ac.uk/~sverre/web/pages/nbody.htm

Comment: @RobJeffries Thanks again! So generally one needs to use these public codes to do their N-body simulations? It is not possible to write up your own N-body solver in, e.g., python?